# Laravel Schema for PostgreSQL Sequence

Tags: postgresql, laravel, schema, sequence

These are my requirements:

1. I have a table(`upload_training_files`)
2. The fields are `id`, `organisation_id`(foreign), `year_id`(foreign), `created_by`, `created_at`, `updated_by`, `updated_at`, `file_path`.
3. The `organisation_id` field refers to `id` field of `organisations`. It should be `auto_incremented` and also should identify with a sequence table(`upload_training_file_organisation_id_fk_seq`).

I have failed to do this in Laravel after repeated attempts. This is my schema:

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateUploadTrainingFileTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('upload_training_file', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigincrements('id');
            $table->biginteger('organisation_id_fk')->unsigned()->unique();
            $table->foreign('organisation_id_fk')->references('organisation_id')->on('organisations');
            $table->biginteger('year_id_fk')->unsigned()->unique();
            $table->foreign('year_id_fk')->references('year_id')->on('year_of_performance');
            $table->biginteger('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->time('created_at')->nullable();
            $table->biginteger('updated_by');
            $table->time('updated_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('file_path')->nullable();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('upload_training_file');
    }
}
```

Here's the snapshot of the database table
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved it.** :)

*You have to drop the primary keys before assigning every new `auto increment` field.*

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUploadTrainingFileTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('upload_training_file', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigincrements('upload_training_file_id');
        });

        Schema::table('upload_training_file', function($table)
        {
            $table->dropPrimary('upload_training_file_upload_training_file_id_primary');
        });

        Schema::table('upload_training_file', function($table)
        {
            $table->bigincrements('organisation_id_fk')->unsigned()->after('id');;
            $table->foreign('organisation_id_fk')->references('organisation_id')->on('organisation');
        });

        Schema::table('upload_training_file', function($table)
        {
            $table->dropPrimary('upload_training_file_organisation_id_fk_primary');
        });

        Schema::table('upload_training_file', function($table)
        {
            $table->bigincrements('year_id_fk')->unsigned()->after('organisation_id_fk');;
            $table->foreign('year_id_fk')->references('year_id')->on('year_of_performance');
            $table->biginteger('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->time('create_date')->nullable();
            $table->biginteger('updated_by')->nullable;
            $table->time('update_date')->nullable();
            $table->string('file_path')->nullable();
        });

        Schema::table('upload_training_file', function($table)
        {
            $table->dropPrimary('upload_training_file_year_id_fk_primary');
            $table->primary('upload_training_file_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('upload_training_file');
    }

}
```

Comment: `dropPrimary` is actually dropping sequences. Thanks for this.